# Are Dialga/Palkia origin forms transferable via Pokemon Home to pokemon Scarlet/Violet?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus, pokemon-scarlet-violet, pokemon-home

As Pokémon Home engages all Pokemon, I wondered if Dialga and Palkia at origin forms could be transferred to Pokemon Scarlet/Violet because they are from Legends Arceus which is an older gen. Also, if they could, would their moves and stats be the same?

I tried with a Garchomp and some moves were changed because there weren’t available in those games, so I didn’t try with Dialga or Palkia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have either forme of Dialga and Palkia in Scarlet and Violet.  They change forme with an item, the Lustrous Globe (Palkia) and the Adamant Orb (Dialga), that you can obtain at the Porto Marinada Auction house once you have the related Pokémon in your SV Pokédex.

Moves may change if Scarlet/Violet doesn't support those moves.  You can ask questions about any specific moves you're concerned about.

Comment: FYI: Transferring a Pokémon between any two Switch games changes its move set to the default one it would have at that level in the game you're transferring to.